# speech-dispatcher won't start on manjaro

Tags: firefox, manjaro

```
$ sudo systemctl start speech-dispatcherd.service
Job for speech-dispatcherd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status speech-dispatcherd.service" and "journalctl -xeu speech-dispatcherd.service" for details.
```

```
ov 10 21:42:32 wiley speech-dispatcher[3128]: [Wed Nov 10 21:42:32 2021 : 132158] speechd: Speech Dispatcher 0.10.2 starting
Nov 10 21:42:32 wiley systemd[1]: speech-dispatcherd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit speech-dispatcherd.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Nov 10 21:42:32 wiley systemd[1]: speech-dispatcherd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ The unit speech-dispatcherd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 10 21:42:32 wiley systemd[1]: Failed to start Speech-Dispatcher an high-level device independent layer for speech synthesis..
░░ Subject: A start job for unit speech-dispatcherd.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit speech-dispatcherd.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1578 and the job result is failed.
```

I'm trying to get speech api to work in firefox. If I type the command to speak from the cli it works fine, but voices array is empty in firefox.

I think speech-dispatcher needs to be running but it won't start on manjaro